# tkz-euclide: Point with same coordinates as another point

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

First I define a point like

```
\tkzDefPoint(0,2){P}
```

then for some reasons (like consistent naming) I want to define another point with the same coordinates like the first one.

The only thing I came up with is

```
\tkzDefPointBy[translation=from P to P](P) \tkzGetPoint{M}
```

This workaround looks a bit ugly to me. Is there a simplier solution?

Comment: `\path (0,2) coordinate (P) coordinate (M);` is okay?

Comment: No, it should be in a separate line. But `\path (P) coordinate (M)` should do the job.

Comment: Perhaps  `\pgfnodealias{P}{M}` is fine ?

Comment: Possible also `\tkzDefPoints{0/2/P,0/2/M}`

Comment: +1 for `\pgfnodealias{P}{M}`. Nice solution!

Comment: ...but the correct order is `\pgfnodealias{M}{P}`.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider yes it's possible! I always forget !!